# Firefox 94 Broke My Hot Keys

Tags: kubuntu, python, firefox, python3, autokey

In Kubuntu 20.04, I use [autokey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoKey) to create hotkeys that launch websites.

Prior to Firefox 94, these hot keys had no difficulty launching pages, but now each time I try to launch a page I get this error:

> Firefox is already running, but is not responding. To use Firefox, you
> must first close the existing Firefox process, restart your device, or
> use a different profile.

[image]

In autokey, the python3 script that gets triggered, upon these hotkeys, is just two lines:

```
import os
os.system("firejail firefox https://askubuntu.com/ &")
```

Notice that I'm using [firejail](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Firejail) to launch firefox, which does require installation:

```
sudo apt install firejail
```

Previously, if Firefox was already running, this would achieve launching the web page into a new tab. Now, even if I include the `-new-tab` argument (described in Firefox's man page), I still cannot launch the page. Now, it only works if Firefox is completely closed at the time I hit the hot keys.

So, something changed upon upgrading to Firefox 94, and I'm hoping someone here can advise a workaround.

Comment: I have seen this a lot now but I use bash scripting for opening instead of Python.  Anyways, I have just changed my `~/.mozilla/firefox` folder so that both my user and group have full Read and Write access to that folder and all folders contained within.  It seems to be working when I test with your Python script.  Might work for you.  https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-already-running-not-responding

Comment: @Terrance : This works when I'm not using firejail. However, in Firefox 93 and prior, the command worked with firejail.

Comment: https://github.com/netblue30/firejail/issues/4670

Comment: Sorry, but your original question did not mention firejail.  When jailing applications it really might make it so that it is not reading your home folder like it should.  It really may be a bug in firejail.

Comment: @Terrance : Well, since Firefox was just auto-upgraded to version 94, I suspect something changed in Firefox. Firejail has no issue with Firefox 93 and lower. It may be a firejail bug, but if so, it is one that wasn't noticeable to me until Firefox 94.

Comment: Or it really could be a bug in Firefox not having access to the folders it needs.

Comment: Firefox Bug ID [1739919](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1739919).

Comment: I have now changed over to Waterfox since it does not seem to suffer from this.  Firefox started doing it again even though I don't use firejail.

Comment: @Terrance Hey, read Roland Kaufmann posts [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1739919). I think it is likely that he discovered the exact change that caused this. Kubuntu 20.04 is a LTS release. Yet, instead of upgrading firejail to 0.9.64.4, in the repository, [as I did request](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firejail/+bug/1949194), they patch an older version instead. Debian 11 stable has a later firejail that Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Perhaps I have misconceptions about the meaning of "Long Term Support"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firefox changed the way it attempts to open new tabs in existing windows, from using X11 in version 93 to using dbus in version 94. The firejail profile in 0.9.62, which is the version currently in the Ubuntu Focal 20.04 repositories, block this. This seems to have been fixed in Firejail version 0.9.64. To upgrade Firejail, add the 'deki' PPA, which currently contains version 0.9.66.:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:deki/firejail
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade -y firejail firejail-profiles
```