# Firejail does not launch Firefox

Tags: firefox, firejail

I has changed my hardware under my ubuntu 20.04 LTS.
Internet working from the first launch, but Firefox from firejail not.
Firefox from stand alone is launch and show.
From firejail is not showed but visible in task manager.

If I start it from command window it write that network disabled:

```
imre@Ubi-20:~$ firejail firefox
Reading profile /etc/firejail/firefox.profile
Reading profile /etc/firejail/whitelist-usr-share-common.inc
Reading profile /etc/firejail/firefox-common.profile
Reading profile /etc/firejail/disable-common.inc
Reading profile /etc/firejail/disable-devel.inc
Reading profile /etc/firejail/disable-exec.inc
Reading profile /etc/firejail/disable-interpreters.inc
Reading profile /etc/firejail/disable-programs.inc
Reading profile /etc/firejail/whitelist-common.inc
Reading profile /etc/firejail/whitelist-var-common.inc
Warning: networking feature is disabled in Firejail configuration file
Parent pid 8282, child pid 8283
Warning: An abstract unix socket for session D-BUS might still be available. Use --net or remove unix from --protocol set.
Warning: cleaning all supplementary groups
Warning: cleaning all supplementary groups
Post-exec seccomp protector enabled
Seccomp list in: !chroot, check list: @default-keep, prelist: unknown,
Child process initialized in 58.04 ms
ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment.
ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment.
```

I tried to reinstall, but it did not helped.
I guess the adapter name is wrong for it, but I did not found in config files /etc/firejail/firefox.profile and firefox-common.profile
The default settings was not changed by me and I do not want to change it.
Please help me if you know the cause of the problem and the solution.

My `/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml` file contents is:

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firefox 94 Broke My Hot Keys](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1373963/firefox-94-broke-my-hot-keys)  I post this because of previous issues with Firejail 0.9.62 which is still in the Ubuntu repos.

Comment: I reinstalled FireFox and Firejail (used your offered last version) and it is working now, but I do not know what was the problem. Thank you for mention the last ver. is newer than the ubuntu app. store.